# Kubernetes Ingress vs. Service with externalIPs

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

If I expose a (single) web service (say `http://a.b.c.d` or `https://a.b.c.d`) on a (small) Kubernetes 1.13 cluster, what is the benefit of using `Ingress` over a `Service` of type `ClusterIP` with `externalIPs [ a.b.c.d ]` alone?

The address `a.b.c.d` is routed to one of my cluster nodes. `Ingress` requires installing and maintaining an [ingress controller](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx), so I am wondering when this is justified.

Comment: Ingress gives you one entry point into the cluster but allows you to access multiple services that are exposed in the ingress definition, whereas if you have to expose multiple services without using an ingress you'll have to manage/remember all of their externalIPs individually. An ingress controller also extends L4/L7 capabilities on top of your service for things like TLS, while/blacklisting IPs, etc.

Comment: @PoweredByOrange In my current (simple) setup I configure addresses such as `a.b.c.d` as secondary IP addresses of a cluster node; so to the degree this is necessary I have to manage/remember them anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've now come across a first concrete example where I see concrete benefit from using `Ingress` over a `Service` with `externalIPs`.

A private Docker registry inside a Kubernetes cluster normally requires TLS credentials. With the Docker image `registry:2` one would have to mount those credentials e.g. from a `ConfigMap` into the container and have certain environment variables in the container (e.g. `REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_CERTIFICATE`) point to them.

As long as one can tolerate insecure access to the registry inside the cluster this becomes easier to mange with `Ingress`. Certificates can be put into a `Secret` which the `Ingress` resource can point to (`kubectl explain ingress.spec.tls.secretName`). There is no more need to pay alternative detailed attention to mounts or environment variables. TLS connections will be terminated at the ingress controller.

Answer (score 1):

- Each service of type ClusterIP has its own public IP address, whereas an Ingress only requires single IP even if you want to provide access to dozens of services.
- You can also forward the client requests to the corresponding service based on the host and path based routing provided by Ingress.
- As Ingresses operate at layer 7 (application layer), it can also provide features like cookie-based session, which is not possible via services.

Comment: For host-based routing (e.g. virtual hosts `a.b.c.d`, `a.b.c.e`) it may also require more than one IP address, right? And the level-7 features help for services replicated to more than one pod, right? Still trying to understand the trade-offs.

Comment: It all depends on what use-case you're trying to achieve. It might be suitable for your use-case or might not.

Answer (score 1):

In Kubernetes, a Service and an Ingress are both used to expose your application to the external world, but they operate at different layers of the networking stack and have different functionalities.

A Service is a Kubernetes resource that provides a stable IP address and DNS name for a set of Pods that provide the same functionality. It allows for load balancing traffic between the Pods, and also provides a way for one Pod to discover and communicate with another Pod using its stable DNS name or IP address. Services are used within the cluster to route traffic between internal components and can also be exposed to the outside world using a NodePort or LoadBalancer.

An Ingress, on the other hand, is a Kubernetes resource that provides a way to expose HTTP and HTTPS routes from outside the cluster to services within the cluster. It acts as a layer 7 (application layer) load balancer, routing incoming traffic based on the request's path or hostname. An Ingress is typically used for applications that require more advanced routing and traffic management capabilities, such as SSL termination, virtual hosting, and path-based routing.

In summary, a Service is used for internal traffic management within the cluster, while an Ingress is used to route external traffic into the cluster and to specific services based on advanced routing rules.

Comment: Hmm, a `Service` of type `LoadBalancer` is also meant for external traffic management, I'd say. BTW this is no longer current.

Comment: True, however it has its limitations since a `Service` is working at a layer 4 on the OSI model, this means that it cannot read HTTP headers, paths or any other protocol above TCP